# CDN related urls says 404 error in my cordova android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am having a strange issue. The files with CDN URL are not loading in my Cordova android application. However, there are many other static files with the path `js/**.js` which is loading fine.

Can anybody tell me this strange issue? This is the first time I am facing the issue.

[image: screenshot of 404 error cdn urls]